# Ordering column of dataframe by group in different directions

Tags: r

I have an example dataframe:

```r
dd <- data.frame(a = factor(c("Hi", "Hi", "Low", "Low"), 
                 levels = c("Low", "Hi"), ordered = T),
                 b = c(1,2,3,4))
dd
#     a b
# 1  Hi 1
# 2  Hi 2
# 3 Low 3
# 4 Low 4
```

I'd like to order column b in ascending order if column a has "Hi" as its value, and I'd like to order column b in descending if column a has "Low" as its value. I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to make use of `desc` and `rev` based on the value of 'a'

```
library(dplyr)
dd %>% 
    arrange(match(a, c("Hi", "Low")),
          case_when(a == "Low"  ~ desc(b), TRUE ~ rev(desc(b))))
```

-output

```
    a b
1  Hi 1
2  Hi 2
3 Low 4
4 Low 3
```

---

Or another option is to convert the numeric column by changing the sign based on the values in 'a'

```
dd %>% 
    arrange(match(a, c("Hi", "Low")), b * c(1, -1)[1 + (a == "Low")])
    a b
1  Hi 1
2  Hi 2
3 Low 4
4 Low 3
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `dplyr::arrange` with an `ifelse` condition. Instead of using `desc` we could use base R `rev` function:

```
library(dplyr)
dd %>% 
    arrange(a, ifelse(a == "Hi", b, rev(b))) %>% 
    arrange(rev(a))
```

output:

```
    a b
1  Hi 1
2  Hi 2
3 Low 4
4 Low 3
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option, multiply `b` by 1 if a has 'High' value else multiply it by -1 and `order` the rows.

```
with(dd, dd[order(a, b * ifelse(a == 'Hi', 1, -1)), ])

#    a b
#4 Low 4
#3 Low 3
#1  Hi 1
#2  Hi 2
```